# Download specific point release version of a dotnet dll / dotnet framework

Tags: .net, debugging, symbols, msdn

Does anyone of you have an idea how to get access to a specific version of a dotnet dll (or the complete .net framework that contains the specific dll)?

We're trying to look into a dmp file, but the usual downloading of debug symbols for the stack frames (in Visual Studio, via the Microsoft Symbol Servers) of a specific dll fails for all of us, with Visual Studio complaining that we (all) don't have the particular dll on our systems (well, the dll *in that exact point release version*).

In this specific case, it's a .Net Framework 4.8 dll, but the client has point release version 4470 of that dll, while we all only have 4455.

The 4.8 framework installer of course quits with "you already have .Net framework 4.8 installed", but it's not even clear if that version came with a regular framework installer or a patch or so, and trying to unzip the offline installer yielded no dll of the same version number either.

Any idea how we could get access to the specific version, patch release or even just the pdb for a specific version like this? Does Microsoft offer a repo with all the released versions somewhere or some way to manually browse their symbol servers?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 4.8 and missing dll's (or even a folder in C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64) while looking for the System.Runtime.CompilerServices dll file